# GCloud: Filter IP Address by 'In Use by' Column as seen in GCP Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, nat, vpc

I am trying to filter out an external IP address used by a Router. When I run the address list command, there is no way I can filter with name as it is auto-created by NAT:

```
 gcloud compute addresses list
NAME                                     ADDRESS/RANGE    TYPE      PURPOSE      NETWORK                       REGION        SUBNET  STATUS
test-network-1234                       10.xxx.0.0/18    INTERNAL  VPC_PEERING  test-network-gcp-1                                  RESERVED
test-network-abcd                       10.xxx.xx.0/18   INTERNAL  VPC_PEERING  test-network-gcp-1                                  RESERVED
nat-auto-ip-15564773-5-xx               xx.xxx.xx.x     EXTERNAL  NAT_AUTO         IN_USE
```

In the console I can see 'In use by' 'Router abcd' column. Is there any way I can filter using this 'In use' parameter?

[image]

EDIT: Added Screenshot of console

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this command. Please include a screenshot of the Console page. When you say "filter", do you specifically mean to include|exclude (?) that line from the output? Or, do you mean something different?

Comment: The underlying REST API method is documented here [`addresses:list`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/list) and the response body that is used by `gcloud` to form the output is defined here [Response Body](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/list#response-body). You can use `gcloud --format=...` to reformat the ouput per your requirements

Comment: Yeah, there is a IP which is used by a router. I need to get this IP address, and the only way I can see through console is through the 'In use by' column (Have added the screenshot). Is there anyway to filter out that IP with the value from this column. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Found this, like other GCP values, the 'in use by' column as represented by users (as given in this [reponse-body](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/list#response-body) ) is given as an API URL.

So I had to create a URL and pass the below values:

```
api_url="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${landscape_project}/regions/${landscape_region}/routers/${router_name}"

external_ip="$(gcloud compute addresses list --filter="users=('${api_url}')" --format=json | jq -r '.[].address')"
```

This way I was able to pass the router_name and create the API URL and pass it as filter to get the external IP.

Hope this helps someone

Cheers!